# Find sudoku grid using OpenCV and Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to detect the grid in sudoku puzzles using OpenCV but I'm having troubles with the last steps (I guess).

What I'm doing is:

- Downsaple the image
- Blur it
- Applying a highpass filter (bilateral)
- Thresholding the image, using adaptive threshold
- Some dilations and erosions

All this gives me the following images:

[image: Original image downsampled and blurred.]

[image]

From now on, I need to detect the grid, and I found a few methods of how to do that but none of them gave me the confidence of being robust enough.

The first one is to find lines using Hough transform but I find a lot of spurious lines.

[image: Hough transform.]

The other is using connected components, which gives me the best results. I tried to implement RANSAC as a way to get the right centroids, but I'm not having good results and also takes a while to get the answer ("a while" is less than 2 seconds, but later I want to use it in real time video).

[image]

[image]

Any idea how this can be done? I mean, how can I discard the wrong centroids and start solving the sudoku?

Comment: Are you input images always slanted? A frontal pic of the sudoku would be a reasonable requirement to expect

Comment: I know, but I'm trying to make it flexible enough to jump to video detection in real time. Do you think it's not a good idea or a starting point?

Comment: you know the grid and you have more than enough points to fit it. no need to recognize all intersections perfectly.

Comment: I would start first with frontal images (or as frontal and not slanted as possible), and after you are satisfied try with slanted images and improve your algorithm's robustness. I think that HoughTransform could give you good results (IMO, it looks promising what you got with it). You can also try the probabilistic version of it. Other idea that *may* work is to do OCR on the image, thus obtaining the "centroid" of the numbers (and with it the center of the square on the grid). Combining Hough with those centroids you can surely filter it out more precisely.

Comment: I didn't know about the probabilistic version. I'm starting with OpenCV and image processing, so this seems a good way to go. Thanks!

Comment: how are you doing the digit recognition?, I have not found a reliable way yet

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Hough transform is definitely the way to go. In fact grid detection is one of the most popular example when introducing this tehcnique (see  [here](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html) and [here](http://aishack.in/tutorials/sudoku-grabber-opencv-plot/)).

I suggest the following steps:

- downsample
- blur
- apply Canny (you should have a good guess what the min/max possible length of a grid line from the used perspective)
- dilate the edge image (canny finds both border of a separator in the grid as different edges, dilation will make these merge again)
- erode (now we have too thick borders, hough would find too many lines)
- apply HoughLines
- merge the similar lines

At the last step you have many possible ways to go and it strongly depends on what you want to do with the results afterwards. For example you could create a new edge image with the found images and apply erosion and hough again, you could use something Fourier-based, or you could just simply filter the lines by some arbitrary threshold values (just to mention a few). I implemented the last one (since conceptually that is the easiest one to do), here is what i did (although i am not at all sure whether this is the best approach or not):

- defined an arbitrary threshold for the rho and theta values
- checked how many times an edge is in these thresholds of another one
- starting from the most similar one I started dropping out lines that are similar to it (this way we will keep the line that is in some sense the 'middle' one among a similar group)
- the remaining lines are the final candidates

See code, have fun:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


filter = False


file_path = ''
img = cv2.imread(file_path)

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
edges = cv2.Canny(gray,90,150,apertureSize = 3)
kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
edges = cv2.dilate(edges,kernel,iterations = 1)
kernel = np.ones((5,5),np.uint8)
edges = cv2.erode(edges,kernel,iterations = 1)
cv2.imwrite('canny.jpg',edges)

lines = cv2.HoughLines(edges,1,np.pi/180,150)

if not lines.any():
    print('No lines were found')
    exit()

if filter:
    rho_threshold = 15
    theta_threshold = 0.1

    # how many lines are similar to a given one
    similar_lines = {i : [] for i in range(len(lines))}
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        for j in range(len(lines)):
            if i == j:
                continue

            rho_i,theta_i = lines[i][0]
            rho_j,theta_j = lines[j][0]
            if abs(rho_i - rho_j) < rho_threshold and abs(theta_i - theta_j) < theta_threshold:
                similar_lines[i].append(j)

    # ordering the INDECES of the lines by how many are similar to them
    indices = [i for i in range(len(lines))]
    indices.sort(key=lambda x : len(similar_lines[x]))

    # line flags is the base for the filtering
    line_flags = len(lines)*[True]
    for i in range(len(lines) - 1):
        if not line_flags[indices[i]]: # if we already disregarded the ith element in the ordered list then we don't care (we will not delete anything based on it and we will never reconsider using this line again)
            continue

        for j in range(i + 1, len(lines)): # we are only considering those elements that had less similar line
            if not line_flags[indices[j]]: # and only if we have not disregarded them already
                continue

            rho_i,theta_i = lines[indices[i]][0]
            rho_j,theta_j = lines[indices[j]][0]
            if abs(rho_i - rho_j) < rho_threshold and abs(theta_i - theta_j) < theta_threshold:
                line_flags[indices[j]] = False # if it is similar and have not been disregarded yet then drop it now

print('number of Hough lines:', len(lines))

filtered_lines = []

if filter:
    for i in range(len(lines)): # filtering
        if line_flags[i]:
            filtered_lines.append(lines[i])

    print('Number of filtered lines:', len(filtered_lines))
else:
    filtered_lines = lines

for line in filtered_lines:
    rho,theta = line[0]
    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)
    x0 = a*rho
    y0 = b*rho
    x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
    y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
    x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
    y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))

    cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),2)

cv2.imwrite('hough.jpg',img)
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Wow, that's exactly what I wanted to do. I'll try to implement it by myself, and if I get stuck, I will look at your code. I'd like to know if this method works with other puzzles too, but I'll have to wait. Thanks!

Comment: that's the spirit! I added some comments to the code to make it a bit easier to understand if you have to get back to it but don't hesitate to ask if you get stuck